# How to update many to many relationships using sqlalchmey ORM in fastapi?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

models.py file that i have used is

```
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__='role'
    role_id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    role_name = Column(String(20),nullable=False)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__='user'
    user_id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String(20),nullable=False)

class UserRoles(Base):
    __tablename__="user_roles"
    user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("User.user_id"),primary_key=True)
    role_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("Role.role_id"),primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Integer,nullable=True)
    user = relationship("User")
    role = relationship("role")
```

I have data in an association table as below which has

| user_id | role_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

I wrote an API to update the data in this table,

```
@app.put('/update_user_roles')
def update_user_roles(data:schmas.payload):
    records = db.query(models.UserRole).filter_by(user_id=payload.user_id).all()
    records.update(payload.roles)
    db.commit()
```

The request payload to the above API is,

```
{"user_id":1, "roles": [1,3]}
```

I am expecting the data in the table to change as below

| user_id | role_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

But iam facing an issue with this,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Help me to achieve this kind of table update using sqlalchemy ORM, automatically removing records and adding new records if necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your model definitions.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have updated the question with models file that i have used please verify this.